# boolean и размер в памяти

Tags: java

Размер (бит)
boolean 8 (в массивах), 32 (не в массивах используется int).
Вот понимаю что всегда int это 32 бита.
А как определить и понять, boolean в массивах и не в массивах?

```
 boolean[] array = {false, true, false}; //здесь boolean 8 бит (т.к в массиве)?
 boolean person = true; // здесь boolean 32 бита (т.к не в массиве?)
```

Можно здесь по подробнее, информация взята у https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: В спецификации нет конкретного размера, поэтому он будет зависеть от конкретной реализации Java машины. Про массивы тут должно быть не размер boolean, а размер ячейки массива. Я сейчас не могу расписать ответ, но можете почитать ответ на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907318/why-is-javas-boolean-primitive-size-not-defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сходил по ссылке, там написана какая-то ересь (как минимум для виртуальной машины HotSpot). Чтобы убедится в этом, возьмём [jol](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) и посмотрим самостоятельно размер занимаемой памяти полем типа `boolean`.

**Example.java**

```
class Example {
    boolean x = true;
}
```

**ShowLayout.java**

```
import org.openjdk.jol.info.ClassLayout;
import org.openjdk.jol.info.GraphLayout;
import org.openjdk.jol.vm.VM;

public class ShowLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] a = {false, true, false};

        // Информация об используемой виртуальной машине
        System.out.println(VM.current().details());

        // Информация о размере поля типа boolean
        System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseClass(A.class).toPrintable());

        // Информация о размере массива
        System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance((Object) a).toPrintable());
        // Информация о структуре массива
        System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(a).toPrintable());
    }
}
```

Компилируем

```
javac -cp jol-cli-0.9-full.jar ShowLayout.java
```

Запускаем

```
java -javaagent:jol-cli-0.9-full.jar ShowLayout
```

Получаем

```
# Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
# Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
# Using compressed klass with 3-bit shift.
# Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
# Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
# Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

A object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE      TYPE DESCRIPTION                               VALUE
      0    12           (object header)                           N/A
     12     1   boolean Example.x                                 N/A
     13     3           (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 16 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 3 bytes external = 3 bytes total

[Z@b81eda8d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE PATH                           VALUE
        76b229190         24 [Z                                  [false, true, false]


[Z object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE      TYPE DESCRIPTION                               VALUE
      0     4           (object header)                           01 a8 ed 81 (00000001 10101000 11101101 10000001) (-2115131391)
      4     4           (object header)                           0b 00 00 00 (00001011 00000000 00000000 00000000) (11)
      8     4           (object header)                           05 00 00 f8 (00000101 00000000 00000000 11111000) (-134217723)
     12     4           (object header)                           03 00 00 00 (00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000) (3)
     16     3   boolean [Z.<elements>                             N/A
     19     5           (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 24 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 5 bytes external = 5 bytes total
```

По цифре 1 в колонке SIZE напротив `Example.x` видим, что "не в массивах" `boolean` имеет размер 1 байт, то есть 8 бит. И по цифре 3 в колонке SIZE напротив `boolean [Z.<elements>` видимо, что три элемента занимают 3 байта. То есть в обоих случаях boolean имеет размер 8-бит.

Comment: Я обновил ссылку

Comment: @MikeMclaren по ссылке всё ещё написана ересь.

Comment: То есть в википедии неправильно написано?

Comment: @MikeMclaren да. Её же пишет кто попало. Верьте только известным учебникам от маститых авторов.

Comment: Видим, что в обоих случаях boolean имеет размер 8 байт. Instance size: 16 bytes это вы 16 поделили на 2?

Comment: Просто не очень понимаю где посмотреть, с jol не работал никогда)

Comment: @MikeMclaren `instance size` - это размер всего объекта вместе с заголовками и выравниванием. Вас должна интересовать цифра 1 (один байт) напротив `boolean Example.x`.

Comment: Так там 1 байт, как вы понимали что в обоих случаях имеет размер 8?

Comment: @MikeMclaren доработал ответ.

Comment: А как насчёт этого? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907318/why-is-javas-boolean-primitive-size-not-defined

Comment: Когда речь идёт о локальных переменных (аргументах методов, в том числе), то да - все примитивы занимают 32-битную ячейку в стеке, кроме `long` и `double` - они занимают по две.

Comment: @AlexKrass а это вообще из другой оперы. То, что виртуальная машина может оперировать только 32-битными ячейками стека - никак не влияет на размеры типов.

Comment: Размер типов не регламентирован в отношении boolean, он может быть любым. Если в JVM от Oracle это байт, то это ещё не значит, что в других он будет таким же.

Comment: @AlexKrass тогда авторам викибука стоило указать на какой именно виртуальной машине они получили те чудесные результаты :)

Comment: Согласен, либо надо было вообще не касаться этой темы размеров в таком виде, либо нормально расписывать как это делают авторы c++ для типа int со всеми нюансами. Считайте мой комментарий простым дополнением к ответу.